# Regex Replace String Between []

Tags: c#, regex

I have this code for replace the content between ()

```
 Regex yourRegex = new Regex(@"\(([^\)]+)\)");

            //Example strings
           string rep1 yourRegex.Replace("This is a (variable) string.", ""); //yields "This is a string."
```

Result is `"This is a string."`

but i have this string "This is a [variable] string". Now how to use Regex for same replace method?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal what should be used instead?

Comment: @DavidHaney I'm not entirely sure because the OP only provided a finite example. If you're coding for that specific case you should use the plain old `String.Replace` if you're coding for the general case RegEx has no chance of working and the implementation is far more complicated. To reliably parse a Context Free Language you need some implementation of a PDA (RegEx is an implementation of an NFA).

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're getting at. You saw `(variable)` as a keyword of sorts. Fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Regex yourRegex = new Regex(@"\(.*\)|\[.*\]");
```

My version uses only matches, whereas yours uses groups which are a little more expensive and unnecessary for what you're trying to accomplish.